# Automorphism group of disjoint cycle graphs of different lengths

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

This question is supplementary to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491203/automorphism-group-of-disjoint-cycle-graphs-n-c-n).

From that question, we know that the automorphism group of the $N$ disjoint cycle graphs of same length $n$ is $S_N \wr D_n$.

**My question:**
What is the Automorphism group of disjoint cycle graphs of different lengths?

**My effort:**
I understand that there will be two cases:

1. More than one cycle graphs with same length
2. Only one cycle graph for each length

Can anyone help me to find for a general solution or special solution to each of these cases?

Comment: There are no automorphisms between cycle graphs of different lengths since there is no bijection between the underlying vertex sets. If your disjoint union looks like $N_1C_{n_1}\sqcup\cdots N_kC_{n_k}$ with $n_i\neq n_j$ for $i\neq j$, you get a direct sum of $S_{N_i}\wr D_{n_i}$

Comment: So, the automorphism group is $\sum_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{n_i}$, right?

Comment: Yes. That is right.