# How to determine the order of $\sum^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$?

Tags: symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product, wreath-product

How can I determine the order of  $\sum^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}$ ?

Here, $i, N_i, m_i$ are positive integers, $S_{N_i}$ is the symmetric group over $N_i$ symbols, $D_{m_i}$ is the dihedral group of order $2 m_i$.

**My effort:**

I understand that the order of semidirect product is product of orders of the groups. So, $|S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}| = |S_{N_i}| |D_{m_i}|$. For non-Abelian group direct sum and direct product [are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581208/exponent-of-the-direct-sum-of-finite-groups-specifically-sumt-i-s-n-i-wr). So, in that sense the order is determined as follows.
$$
|\sum^t_i S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}| = \Pi_i |S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i}|
$$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: First, you might wat to avoid using the sum symbol for direct products of non-abelian groups. It will just confuse people. Second, the wreath product is not the semidirect product of the two groups, it is the semidirect product of one with a number of copies of the other, depending on how one identifies the first with a permutation group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, so how can I determine the order of a wreath product?

Comment: By looking at the definition, pretty much.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, we know $S_{N} \wr D_{m} = \left( S_{N} \right)^m \rtimes D_m$. So is $|S_{N} \wr D_{m}| = m | S_{N}| |D_m|$?

Comment: No, the order of $G^m$ is $|G|^m$, not $m|G|$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, which means $|S_{N} \wr D_{m}| =  | S_{N}|^m |D_m|$

Comment: Yes, precisely.